# How to stop pwm after generate few pulse in Arduino?

Tags: arduino

I'm trying to generate pulse from Arduino to driver motor stepper 5 phase.
 The driver only needs pulse to make motor stepper work. My problem is when I'm using code like this

```
for(int i=0; i <= 125; i++)
{
    //analogWrite(13,125);
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(300);
    digitalWrite(13, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(300);
}
digitalWrite(13,LOW);
delay(3000);
```

Stepper motor can work perfectly, but after more than 10 rotation,
the angle of the motor did not return to the original place. Can we use pwm in Arduino like that? So after generating 5000 pulses using pwm, we stop the pwm?

Comment: can you make it more clear?

Comment: well, i bought driver motor stepper, 
the output from the driver was cw+ dan cw-, 
the stepper will move if we gave pulse from the driver, 
1 pulse (1 high & 1 low) will make the stepper move 0.72 degre
so if i want to move that stepper we will need 125 pulse
when i generate pulse using code in the above, 
stepper motor didnt move 90 degree,, (there was error 1 or 2 degree)

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
#include <TimerOne.h>
const byte CLOCKOUT = 11;
volatile byte counter=0;

void setup() {
    Timer1.initialize(15);         //Every 15 microseconds change the state of the pin in the wave function giving a period of 30 microseconds 
    Timer1.attachInterrupt(Onda);  
    pinMode (CLOCKOUT, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(CLOCKOUT,HIGH);
}
void loop() {
    if (counter>=6000){               //With 6000 changes you should achieve the amount of pulses you need
        Timer1.stop();               //Here I create the dead time, which must be in HIGH
        PORTB = B00001000;
        counter=0;
        delayMicroseconds(50);
        Timer1.resume();
    }
}
void Onda(){
    PORTB ^= B00001000;   //Change pin status
    counter+=1;
}
```

I just cant not eliminate the jitter. If you find a solution let me know